# Stop publishing when there are no subscribers and auto start when there are subscribers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

How would I implement a `RACSignal` that would stop publishing when there are no subscribers to it and auto start when there are subscribers?

Here is a scenario:

Let us say I have a `currentLocationSignal` in the `AppDelegate`. 
My `LocationViewController` would subscribe to the `currentLocationSignal` when view loads and unsubscribe (dispose) when view unloads. Since it takes few seconds to get the current location, I would like to always subscribe to the `currentLocationSignal` when the app opens (and auto unsubscribe after few seconds), so by the time I arrive to `LocationViewController` I would get an accurate location.
So there can be more then one subscribers to the signal. When the first subscriber listens, it needs to start calling `startUpdatingLocation` and when there are no subscribers it needs to call `stopUpdatingLocation`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! Normally, you'd use [RACMulticastConnection](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACMulticastConnection.h) for use cases like this, but, because you want the signal to be able to *reactivate* later, a connection isn't suitable on its own.

The simplest answer is probably to mimic how a connection works, but with the specific behaviors you want. Basically, we'll keep track of how many [subscribers](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/FrameworkOverview.md#subscription) there are at any given time, and start/stop updating the location based on that number.

Let's start by adding a `locationSubject` property. The subject needs to be a [RACReplaySubject](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACReplaySubject.h), because we always want new subscribers to get the most recently sent location immediately. Implementing updates with that subject is easy enough:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [self.locationSubject sendNext:locations.lastObject];
}
```

Then, we want to implement the signal that tracks and increments/decrements the subscriber count. This works by using a `numberOfLocationSubscribers` integer property:

```
- (RACSignal *)currentLocationSignal {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        @synchronized (self) {
            if (self.numberOfLocationSubscribers == 0) {
                [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            }

            ++self.numberOfLocationSubscribers;
        }

        [self.locationSubject subscribe:subscriber];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            @synchronized (self) {
                --self.numberOfLocationSubscribers;
                if (self.numberOfLocationSubscribers == 0) {
                    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
                }
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

In the above code, the `+createSignal:` block is invoked every time a new subscriber is added to the returned signal. When that happens:

1. We check to see if the number of subscribers is currently zero. If so, the just-added subscriber is the first one, so we need to enable (or re-enable) location updates.
2. We hook the subscriber directly up to our `locationSubject`, so the values from the latter are automatically fed into the former.
3. Then, at some future time, when the subscription is [disposed of](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#disposal-cancels-in-progress-work-and-cleans-up-resources), we decrement the count and stop location updates if appropriate.

Now, all that's left is subscribing to the `currentLocationSignal` on startup, and automatically unsubscribing after a few seconds:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Use a capacity of 1 because we only ever care about the latest
    // location.
    self.locationSubject = [RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1];

    [[self.currentLocationSignal
        takeUntil:[RACSignal interval:3]]
        subscribeCompleted:^{
            // We don't actually need to do anything here, but we need
            // a subscription to keep the location updating going for the
            // time specified.
        }];

    return YES;
}
```

This subscribes to `self.currentLocationSignal` immediately, and then automatically disposes of that subscription when the `+interval:` signal sends its first value.

Interestingly, `-[RACMulticastConnection autoconnect]` *used* to behave like `-currentLocationSignal` above, but [that behavior was changed](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/235) because it makes side effects wildly unpredictable. This use case should be safe, but there are other times (like when making a network request or running a shell command) when automatic reconnection would be horrible.

Comment: thanks. implemented it at https://github.com/prabirshrestha/reactive-cocoa-playground/blob/fcf5aac374340ceaa9197a68d0cc9a5d47d72a2c/src/reactive-cocoa-playground/LocationManager/LocationManager.m